# Why is does the layout disappear and reappear when selecting a long word from an EditText that wrapped over to the next line?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

The UI seems to disappear and reappear when selecting the current long word that reached the next line from an EditText.

It's hard to explain but for example, I'm typing a word "jdbfeergerbgherhgbrehgherhbgerbgherbgerrebghrebgrbegrebgjherbghebrghbehgbrgbejrgb" and it wrapped over to the next line/s. When I select it while I'm not yet adding a space, like by long pressing it or by using the delete gesture of Google Keyboard, the EditText and the views beside it seems to disappear and then reappear.

I've tried removing the starting constraint of the EditText and it worked but I can't achieve the layout I want by removing the starting constraint.

I tried putting the EditText in another container like a CardView or a LinearLayout but it doesn't help.

I've also tried by putting the them outside of the bottom bar and it doesn't help as well.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/encrypt_button"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nav_drawer_btn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/encrypt_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've removed the paddings and margin as I find them unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the Android Manifest inside the `activity` tag fixes the problem.